# Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (python sockets)

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to learn how to use sockets using this tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm
I have copied the code from the site into my directory and ran it exactly as was done in the tutorial but got errors. Here is the code from the tutorial.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = 'localhost' # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print("asdf")
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()                # Close the connection
```

and client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

These are the console commands I ran:

```
python server.py &
python client.py
```

I got this errors after running the command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((host, port))
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/soc    ket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

In case this is helpful, the version of python I am using is Python 2.7.10 and I use a mac that is version 10.12.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like an issue with what `socket.gethostname()` returns. Try using `host = 'localhost'` instead.

Comment: that seems to work, I'll put the rest of the code in now and see if it still works

Comment: so your fix got me past the problem with the server file but the client file still doesn't work

Comment: I would suggest accepting this answer and opening anther question to address the new issue.

Comment: sure, Just did, I'll ask a new question now, if you don't mind looking at it that would be great

Comment: One quick thing. Make sure you do the same thing for your client file: `host = 'localhost'`

Comment: `do you figure its worth pointing this error out to tutorialspoint.com?` Might be worth doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs of [`socket.gethostname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname):

> Return a string containing the hostname of the machine where the
>   Python interpreter is currently executing.
>
> Note: `gethostname()` doesn’t always return the fully qualified domain
>   name; use `getfqdn()` for that.

The host IP is not the same as the hostname. You have a couple of options:

1. You can either manually assign `host` to `0.0.0.0` or `localhost`
2. You can also query [`socket.gethostbyname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname):

   ```
   host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # or socket.getfqdn() if the former doesn't work
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your code. Here's the **server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file 
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object 
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5) 
c,addr= s.accept()


print "Got connection from the ", addr
c.send('Thank you for connecting')

c.close()                # Close the connection
```

Here's the **client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))

msg = (s.recv(1024))
print msg
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

I hope it will help